# A sequence of measurable sets $\{A_n\}$ such that $f = \sum_n 1_{A_n}a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I have the following problem but I have really no clue how to solve it.

> Suppose that $(a_n)$  is a sequence of non-negative numbers such that an $a_n\rightarrow0$ and $\sum_n a_n=\infty$. Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function on a measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$. Show that there are measurable sets $\{A_n\}$ such that $$f =\sum_n 1_{A_n}a_n$$

I can't really think of any strategy to approach this problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose $f$ is a real measurable function? That is, $f:(X,\Sigma)\longrightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$? Or perhaps $f:(X,\Sigma)\longrightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{L})$? Here I mean $\mathcal{B}$ for Borel and $\mathcal{L}$ for Lebesgue.

Comment: Look at the proof of the famous theorem that says: For non-negative measurable function there exists a non-decreasing sequence of simple functions $s_n$ such that $\lim_n s_n=f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $a_n \to 0$ but $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N} a_n = \infty$ for each $r\in\Bbb R$ exists a subsequence s.t. the sum of the subsequence equals $r$.
Or more formally there is a sequence $(b^r_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ with $b^r_n \in \{0,1\}$ s.t. $$r = \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} b_na_n$$ by choosing $$b^r_n = \begin{cases} 1, &\mbox{ if } \sum_\limits{k=1}^{n-1} b^r_ka_k + a_n < r \\ 0, &\mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Choose $A_n = \{\omega\in\Omega: b_n^{f(\omega)} = 1\}$ then $$f =\sum_n 1_{A_n}a_n$$ by construction.

Still need to be shown that $A_n$s are measurable, that's your part :-)